# Invoke of a UserControl doesn't work

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a form (`MainPage`) and I set a `UserControl` in it some times, So I write a method in that form like this to invoke:

```
delegate void containerPanelCallback(UIPart uiPart);
public void IncludeUIPart(UIPart uiPart)
{
    if (this.containerPanel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        containerPanelCallback d = new containerPanelCallback(IncludeUIPart);
        containerPanel.Invoke(d, new object[] { uiPart });
    }
    else
    {
        containerPanel.Controls.Clear();
        containerPanel.Controls.Add(uiPart);
    }
    uiPart.Size = this.containerPanel.Size;
    uiPart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

`UIPart` class inherit from `UserControl` that my UserControls inherit from `UIPart`.

This method and invoke launched like this:

```
public class myClass
{ 
...
private static MainPage _frmMain;
private static myUIPart6 UIP6;
...
public static void aMethod(/* Some arguments */)
{
    UIP6 = new myUIPart6 { /* Some settings of properties */ };
    _frmMain.IncludeUIPart(UIP6);
    _frmMain.Show(); /*Throws an error*/
}
...
}
```

The error is:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MainPage' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I found many questions and many answers here about this error, But I can't figure it out why it is throwing at `_frmMain.Show();`?, Should I invoke something else? Or Am I in a wrong way? Is it related to creation of Handle of my UserControl?

Comment: How do you call `aMethod`?

Comment: Invoke() must be called for any/all operations with the UI performed from a non-main thread. In your example, you use Invoke on when calling IncludeUIPart(), but no Invoke() when calling _frmMain.Show. Try wrapping the whole aMethod in Invoke() and remove Invoke call from IncludeUIPart()

Comment: I think you are in early 2000-th as developer as well as your joke ;)

Comment: So on that way you shouldn't joke on serious things ;)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I have a `Send` Thread that calls `aMethod()` ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following code:

```
public static void aMethodCaller(){
 if (_frmMain.InvokeRequired)
   _frmMain.Invoke(new Action(aMethod));
 else
   aMethod();
}
```

and replace all references to aMethod() in your code to aMethodCaller()

Below is the sample code:

```
class Foo 
{
    static Form _frmMain;
    public static void aMethod()
    {
        _frmMain.Show(); 
    }        
    public static void aMethodCaller()
    {
        if (_frmMain.InvokeRequired)
            _frmMain.Invoke(new Action(aMethod));
        else
            aMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: aMethod is static according to the code in your question, so you can't call it as _frmMain.aMethod(), can you?
-- hmm, this appears to be an answer to the already deleted op's comment

Comment: Why're people post ever and ever again the wrong solution to this problem. It's working yes, but it's a design fault when you have to use Inovke to change your UI from another thread.

Comment: @user743414, you are right. But the world is imperfect. Every design is faulty, because there is always room for perfection ;-) Seriously, people want solutions that work much more than "correct" solutions. Then they find problems in the faulty but working solutions, that's how they learn

Comment: Yarkovoy Yeah but, when every one did this. Softwaredevelopment doesn't get better. :) I was on enrage, because I read exactly that solution more than one time that day here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `_frmMain.Show()` isn't guarded by any invocation requirement check. So you're probably calling it in a background thread.

Comment: If your `aMethod` is called from a non-UI thread then you have to check for `InvokeRequired` in `aMethod` and execute `_frmMain.Show()` in the proper thread the same way you do it in `IncludeUIPart`.

Comment: It doesn't matter _where_ you call it, the important thing is _how_ you call it, i.e. from which thread.

Comment: I have a thread `Send` that calls inside of `MyUIPart5` that calls `aMethod`.

Comment: See my first comment then.

Comment: Thanks to clarify me about that, And I should do same thing like Denis Yarkovoy's answer or there is some other way?

Comment: The easiest way is to just `_frmMain.Invoke(new Action(() => _frmMain.Show()));`

Comment: Thanks, And I should also use `invoke` over my form. And I can't only invoke my UserControl in anyway.